# PHP DOMDocument | ends by null char (\u0)

Tags: php, domdocument

I noticed that on this url: [http://www.bubbleroom.se/sv/kläder/kvinna/controlbody/bodys/body-nero](http://www.bubbleroom.se/sv/kl%C3%A4der/kvinna/controlbody/bodys/body-nero) there is a null character `\u0` in the tag with id `prodText`.

The whole document seems to end by this null char when attempting to extract anything else after this character.

---

#### Edit

The code that "doesn't" work. It works, but not when there's a null char in the `$html` string

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

return new DOMXPath($dom);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you post the code that doesn't work?

Comment: @AmalMurali The issue has been resolved, but I update the question if there is any other input that could be useful to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue by simply filtering the html before creating an xpath instance with the following code:

```
$html  = str_replace("\0", "", $html);
```